# Laravel: difference between login with and without Remember Me option?

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a question about the default Laravel Remember Me option below the login form. I use the default built-in `LoginController`.
When I read the Laravel documentation, then I read about the Remember option:

> "which will keep the user authenticated indefinitely, or until they
>   manually logout"

Ok. Now I do a test:

- I uncheck the Remember Me checkbox, and I login. Then I close the browser. I open my browser and goto my app: I am still logged-in.
- Then I select the checkbox Remember Me, log in, close browser, open browser: exactly the same result: I am still logged-in....

How is that possible? What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use remember me, Laravel puts cookie with token that is used to log you in next time you visit the page (in case you are somehow logged out I will explain later).

Laravel by default uses session that is valid for 2 hours (you can set this up in config), so if you close your browser while logged in and then attempt to open **same** browser again in window of 2 hours server will not notice the change.

"Log out somehow"

- well obviously by clicking logout in application
- clearing up browser cache by browser itself or by 3rd party program
- using different browser (this is just for clarification)
- using incognito mode (this is just for clarification)
- using different computer and browser without sync feature (this is for clarification)

---

To answer your question "whats the difference?":

If you use remember me, Laravel will set cookie with token that is used instead of credentials (name:password combination) while logging in, and the process is invisible for user.

If you do not use remember me, you can be signed in only for 2 hours (or whatever is set in config file) without action. The fact that browser keeps session information even after its closed is considered as feature of the browser).

Comment: So basically, if we want to apply this logic to other languages, we would get that without a "remember me", the token is only valid for a short period of time, vs a long-lasting token (e.g. two days or a week)?